# Global variables in PHP

Tags: php

I'm writing a script that will select a random word from among words in an input file, multiple times. Now calling `file()` multiple times seems inefficient, so I'm thinking of having a global array for the words from the file and a function that will load the file into the array (called before selecting random words). Why doesn't it work?

```
global $words;

function init_words($file)
{
    $words = file($file);
    $count = count($words);
    echo "$count words<br>\n"; // "3 words"
}

init_words("/foo/bar");
$count = count($words);
echo "$count words<br>\n"; // "0 words"
```

Comment: The semantics in PHP are a bit different. Global variables aren't what they are in C for example. They need to be invited into the function scope.

Comment: *(related)* [PHP Global in Functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166087/php-global-in-functions)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to declare `$words` global within the function itself. See:

```
$words = '';

function init_words($file)
{
    global $words;
    $words = file($file);
    $count = count($words);
    echo "$count words<br>\n"; // "3 words"
}
```

I suggest you review the [variable scope chapter](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) in the PHP manual.

As an aside I would never write this code in this way. Avoid globals unless they are absolutely necessary.

I would write your code this way to avoid this problem:

```
function init_words($file)
{
    $words = file($file);
    $count = count($words);
    echo "$count words<br>\n"; // "3 words"
    return $words;
}

$words = init_words("/foo/bar");
$count = count($words);
echo "$count words<br>\n"; // "3 words"
```

Please see the [returning values chapter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php) in the PHP manual for more information on this.

Comment: This.  `global` works differently then what most people expect in PHP.  It doesn't define a variable as global scope, instead it says that "for the following scope, I want to use the global version of [var], not a local one."

Answer (score 2):

```
$words = null;

function init_words($file)
{
    global $words;
    $words = file($file);
    $count = count($words);
    echo "$count words<br>\n"; // "3 words"
}

init_words("/foo/bar");
$count = count($words);
echo "$count words<br>\n"; // "0 words"
```

The `global` part should go inside your function

*side note:* it is not always the best to use global operators

Answer (score 2):

You want `global $words;` inside the function. Better yet, use the superglobal [`$GLOBALS`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php).

Comment: [Variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php): Note: Using global keyword outside a function is not an error. It can be used if the file is included from inside a function.

Comment: @Jared Oh, of course, bad choice of words by me. Updated.

Comment: @phihag $GLOBALS has got to be the best way of using a global variable inside a function. mitigates spagetti code. something tells me php wants to enforce OO programming. :)

Answer (score 0):

first you need to store the words in a serialised formant so that means

```
$file_location = "/foo/bar/words.txt";
$words = array("game", "cool", "why");
$words = serilize($words);
write_words_file($words, $filelocation); //Create the function so it can write to a file
```

then you will need to edit your init_words

```
function init_words($file)
{
    global $words;
    $data = file_get_contents($file);
    $words = unserialize($data);
    $count = count($words);
    echo "$count words<br>\n"; // "3 words"
}

init_words("/foo/bar/words.txt");
$count = count($words);
echo "$count words<br>\n"; // "0 words"
```

Comment: Why do they need to be serialized? The `file()` method the OP is using turns each new line in a file into a item in an array. There is no need for serialisation.

Comment: then you dont need to serialize it.

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, you could use the following and avoid usage of `global` altogether:

```
function init_words($fname)
{
    $w = file($fname, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);  // We don't want the trailing spaces or empty lines.
    $c = count($w);

    return array($w, $c);
}

list($words, $count) = init_words("Some_File.txt");
```

In such a situation if you ever had to do any manipulation of the list of words, you can handle it all within `init_words()` as opposed to elsewhere in the script.